# VSTO Outlook add-in installation Fail

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I published a VSTO project in visual studio 2019, a .vsto, and .exe file is generated. I would like to install the add-in to another PC and installation is failed.

is anyone knows what happened to the error?

Here are the steps that I followed to publish the project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019

Here is the install log file. Thank you very much.

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 10.0.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Release' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read integer value 394802
Setting value '394802 {int}' for property 'DotNetFull_Release'
Reading value 'v4' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\OS Integration'
Read integer value 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'DotNetFull_OSIntegrated'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNetFull_OSIntegrated] = 1 {int}
Property: [DotNetFull_Release] = 394802 {int}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThan' on property 'DotNetFull_Release' and value '461808': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.1.0': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4'
Read string value '10.0.60301'
Setting value '10.0.60301 {string}' for property 'VSTORuntimeVersionOfficeInstalled'
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'VSTORuntimeVersionInstalled'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)':
Property: [VSTORuntimeVersionOfficeInstalled] = 10.0.60301 {string}
Running checks for command 'VSTOR40\vstor_redist.exe'
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'VSTORuntimeVersionInstalled' was not defined
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VSTORuntimeVersionOfficeInstalled' and value '10.0.50903': true
Result of checks for command 'VSTOR40\vstor_redist.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
EULA for components 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\ENOTI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD2D5D.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\ENOTI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD2D5D.tmp\"
(09-06-2020 PM 02:56:57) Downloading 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=863262&clcid=0x409' to 'C:\Users\ENOTI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD2D5D.tmp\'
Download completed at 09-06-2020 PM 02:56:57
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\ENOTI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD2D5D.tmp\DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)', phase BeforePackage
Reading value 'Release' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read integer value 394802
Setting value '394802 {int}' for property 'DotNetFull_Release'
Reading value 'v4' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\OS Integration'
Read integer value 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'DotNetFull_OSIntegrated'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNetFull_OSIntegrated] = 1 {int}
Property: [DotNetFull_Release] = 394802 {int}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThan' on property 'DotNetFull_Release' and value '461808': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.1.0': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\ENOTI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD2D5D.tmp\DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Installing using command 'C:\Users\ENOTI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD2D5D.tmp\DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe' and parameters ' /q /norestart /ChainingPackage FullX64Bootstrapper /lcid 1033'
Process exited with code 1307
Status of package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)' after install is 'InstallFailed'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message found in your log:

```
Status of package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)' after install is 'InstallFailed'
```

You just need to install prerequisites correctly first. One of them is the .net framework.

The article mentioned in your post includes the following points:

```
Choose the Prerequisites button.

In the Prerequisites dialog box, ensure that the Create setup program to install prerequisite components check box is selected.

In the Choose which prerequisites to install list, select the check boxes for Windows Installer 4.5 and the appropriate .NET Framework package.

For example, if your solution targets the .NET Framework 4.5, select the check boxes for Windows Installer 4.5 and Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Full.
```

It seems you need to add .net framework 4.7.2 if it's your target framework.